# How to send a transactional email with attachment with Google Apps Script and Mailchimp API

Tags: google-apps-script, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I am trying to figure out how to send attachments in transactional emails with Mailchimp. According to the [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/), the `attachments` array must contain objects with `type`, `name` and `content` properties. The one that I can't figure out is `content`. And surprisingly I could find a related question on SO.

The documentation says its value must be:

> the content of the attachment as a base64-encoded string

So I have this function that does send the email, but the attachment content is corrupt (the name and type look fine):

```js
const sendEmail = emailObj => {
  console.log('sendEmail()');
  const URL = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send';

  const { html, subject, toEmail, attachmentId } = emailObj;

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(attachmentId);
  const type = file.getMimeType();
  const name = file.getName();
  const content = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());

  const options = {
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      key: 'key',
      message: {
        from_email: 'email@domain.com',
        subject,
        html,
        to: [
          {
            email: toEmail,
            type: 'to',
          },
        ],
        attachments: [
          {
            type,
            name,
            content,
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  };


  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
  return emailObj;
};
```

The attachment comes in as a corrupt PDF file with the right name.

I have also tried setting the content to:

- `file.getBlob()`
- `file.getBlob().getDataAsString()`
- `file.getBlob().getBytes()`

Hopefully someone has done this before :)

Comment: I tried converting Base64 of my files in drive online and this method worked. `content = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())`. `base64Encode` works on byte array. If it has special characters, you can add specific charset (e.g. Utilities.Charset.UTF_8) to it. If it still doesn't work, then try the variation `base64EncodeWebSafe`. Just always try to have the byte array as its parameter.

Comment: best way to test it is that you check whether the one you get as base64 is working when you try to convert it into a file. You can try online sites that convert base64 to file or create a drive file from it and check if it is a proper base64. Base64 on `getDataAsString` return will error as I have tested. raw bytes is needed so `getBytes` did the trick on my test.

Comment: @NaziA Thank you, this worked! If you write up an answer, I will be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: I am glad it worked @DmitryKostyuk, I have created an answer based on my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to test fully the API due to my current limitations, I tried converting the Base64 of my files in drive online and this method worked.

```
content = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())
```

`base64Encode` works on byte array as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata) suggests. If it has special characters, you can add specific charset (e.g. `Utilities.Charset.UTF_8`) to it.

If it still doesn't work, then try the variation `base64EncodeWebSafe`. Just always use its byte array as its parameter.

Best way to test it is that you check whether the one you get as base64 is working when you try to convert it into a file. You can try online sites that convert base64 to file or create a drive file from it and check if it is a proper base64. Base64 on `getDataAsString` return will error as I have tested. Raw bytes is needed so `getBytes` did the trick on my test.

Comment: `Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())` did the job perfectly, thank you!